# Functions that remember their values

Tags: functions, function-construction, syntax

Can someone explain what is going on with the following ...

```
func[y_] := func[y] = (Print["Hello world !!!"];)

func[1]
```

> Hello world !!!

```
func[2]
```

> Hello world !!!

```
func[1] (*nothing printed*)

func[2] (*nothing printed*)
```

As I understand it ()  are used so the function remembers its values, but as you see when I repeat `func[1]`, nothing.

If I take out the `y` in `f[y]`, it prints. If I define the function as `f[y_] := (...)` (without `f[y] =` ), it prints.

I'm sure there is a simple explanation, any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is one tiny syntactic subtlety in your code: `(expr;)` will return Null regardless of what `expr` evaluates to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason can be learned by inputting the following:

```
?func
```

This outputs the values currently assigned to your function `func`:

> Global`func

```
func[1]=Null

func[2]=Null

func[y_]:=func[y]=Print[Hello world !!!]
```

When a function is evaluated that only prints, it assigns it a value of `Null` which is remembered by the memoization. The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Print.html) covers this under "Properties & Relations".

Comment: Of course, that makes complete sense. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: That isn't the only reason. The statement `(Print[...];)` is interpreted as `CompoundExpression[Print[...], Null]`, and [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html) returns the result of the last expression which is `Null`. So, the OP got hit with it twice, but only the `CompoundExpression` applies here.

Comment: @rcollyer Yep, but the OP's conundrum exists in both cases with and without the semicolon, so I covered the most egregious issue.

Answer (score 12):

In some languages Print behaves like the identity function. But as noted, Print in Mathematica returns Null.

---

I want to make clear what is going on with the memoization idiom, for those who might be confused by it. I know I didn't really understand it at first.

```
func[y_] := func[y] = Print["Hello world !!!"];
```

This is clearer if it's written like this:

```
func[y_] := (
    func[y] = Print["Hello world !!!"];
);
```

`:=` means evaluate each time.
`=` means only evaluate this once.

`func[y_]` means "match any singular pattern"
`func[y]` means "match *only* y's current value"

So the internal assignment is specifying an explicit value for a specific `y`. And the reason this idiom makes sense is because Mathematica essentially allows you to create multiple definitions for a single function. Examples:

```
myPrint[l_List] := Do[Print[x], {x, l}];
myPrint[else_] := Print[else];

f[1] = 1;
f[2] = 1;
f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2];
```

So the memoization idiom is an automated version of this.