# Persistent memoized functions

Tags: functions, save, persistence

I'm inspired to make use of "remembering the function values" technique from here:
[Functions that remember their values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/functions-that-remember-their-values)

The only question is: how can I save the function, along with its values stored as well, into some kind of file, so that next time when I load the file, i.e., the function into Mathematica, I can access all the values I stored last time.

Comment: I think that's what `DumpSave` is for. Note however that `DumpSave` creates a `.mx` file, which to my understanding is a file format that isn't very cross-platform (and maybe even cross-version) compatible.

Comment: [`Save`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save.html) also will work.  All this is described in my own answer [(2008)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/121) for which I would consider this question "already has an answer" (i.e. duplicate) but I do not wish to vote alone.

Comment: Strongly related: "[The best way to construct a function with memory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5291299/590388)."

Answer (score 0):

DynamicModule[{x,y, ...]},expr]
represents an object which maintains the same local instance of the symbols x, y,  ...] in the course of all evaluations of Dynamic objects in expr. Symbols specified in a DynamicModule will by default have their values maintained even across Wolfram System sessions.

Comment: I don't think DynamicModule is meant for this purpose ...